# "Failed to delete integration runtime." Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have two integration runtimes(both are self-hosted). When I try to delete one I get an error message.

```
Error: Failed to delete integration runtime.
Detail: The document cannot be deleted since it is referenced by AzureSqlDatabaseContoso.
```

But this is not true. At the moment there is no such thing as "AzureSqlDatabaseContoso". Perhaps it might have been there before. I did a search on source code as well, it is not present in the whole Git branch.
How can I delete it ?

Comment: Do you have any other Data Factory which shared this self-hosted integration runtime?

Comment: I have but the object was not present

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me before.  I just recreated the phantom object with the same name, associated it with the IR to be deleted, and then deleted the newly-recreated object (AzureSqlDatabaseContoso, in this case).

After that, ADF let me delete the underlying IR. Weird, but it worked for me.

Comment: I had to create couple of components more and in the end I could not delete one of the components I created. As apparently there was another non-existent link. Then I renamed the file in source folder in git and reloaded , then was able to delete. more wierdness but it works!

Comment: One can even delete the fantom IR directly from git

Answer (score 0):

the answer is what JeffRamos posted. Another option is to rename the file and 'name' field in git source and reload the adf and delete it there.

```
Source/linkedService/AzureKeyVault.json
```

rename this to

```
Source/linkedService/test.json
```

json content

```
{
    "name": "AzureKeyVault",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureKeyVault",
        "typeProperties": {
            "baseUrl": "https://mykv.vault.azure.net/"
        }
    }
}
```

Rename "name" field

```
{
    "name": "test",
    "properties": {
        "annotations": [],
        "type": "AzureKeyVault",
        "typeProperties": {
            "baseUrl": "https://mykv.vault.azure.net/"
        }
    }
}
```